Redirect URL using python requests behaving differently on local vs server
I have a shortened url:
https://dl.flipkart.com/s/XermJqNNNN
which expands to:
https://www.flipkart.com/beatxp-prime-deep-tissue-electric-massage-gun-machine-full-body-pain-relief-percussion-massager/p/itmb8e3cc771527c?pid=MASGHMJHYUJCN3WQ&cmpid=product.share.pp&_refId=PP.f843e983-04ea-4b65-b58d-413f2d9ee16f.MASGHMJHYUJCN3WQ&_appId=CL
I want to retrieve this redirected URL.
import requests
def get_original_url(short_url):
    try:
        response = requests.get(short_url, allow_redirects=False)
        if 'Location' in response.headers:
            return response.headers['Location']
        else:
            return "Original URL not found in the response."
    except requests.exceptions.RequestException as e:
        return f"An error occurred: {e}"

I tried the above method which gives me the correct redirect URL in my local system(Windows). But returns the same shortened URL when deployed to the app service on Render(Linux).

This sounds like a problem with the way you're creating the redirect in the server-side code, not a problem with this code.

Hi Barmar, Could you please elaborate on your comment. Is this not the right way to create a redirect within the server? Is there any alternative way to achieve this in the server?

I thought the problem you're having is with the response you're getting from requests.get(short_url, allow_redirects=False). So you need to look at the code that responds to the dl.flipkar.com URL, not the code you posted here.

This code is just passing along whatever it receives from dl.flipkart.com.
